# What is the right way to authenticate to the GCP Cloud Tasks enqueue API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have this code:

```
import {v2beta3} from "@google-cloud/tasks";
const project = 'xxxxxxx'
const location = 'yyyyyyy'
const queue = 'zzzzzzzzz'

const client = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient()
const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue)
const payload = {eventId: "fred"}
const convertedPayload = JSON.stringify(payload)
const body = Buffer.from(convertedPayload).toString('base64');
const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: "POST",
    url: "https://webhook.site/9sssssssssss",
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: "aaaaaaaaaa@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body,
  },
};

(async function() {
  try {
    const [response] = await client.createTask({parent, task});
    console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}());
```

When I run it from my laptop, it just works, which seems unauthenticated to me.  Anyone can now enqueue a task on my queue.

What is the right way to authenticate to the GCP Cloud Tasks enqueue API?

Comment: Your application running on your laptop has to be authenticated otherwise the `oidcToken` part would fail at `client.createTask()`.

Comment: I thought the same @JohnHanley - where are the local creds stored, so I can remove and retest?

Comment: Your application is defaulting to ADC (Application Default Credentials). You have either set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to a service account JSON key file or you are using the credentials created by the CLI command `gcloud auth application-default login`. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/revoke

Comment: Yes, you are right @JohnHanley, the creds are in ~/.config .  I did a gcloud auth months ago and forgot about it.  Thanks for clearing it up for me!

Comment: Post an answer with your solution after testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley pointed out in the comments, my local app was using Application Default Credentials to authenticate itself.  When I switched to a different gcloud account by doing this:

`gcloud auth application-default login`

I get this error message when I try to run the code:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource "projects/yyyyyyy/locations/europe-west1/queues/default-xxxxxx" (or the resource may not exist).
```